# Updating WooCommerce Admin Shipping Order Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In functions.php I am trying to use this, but it is not working:

```
function rt_woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['first_name']['value'] = $_GET['f'];
    $fields['last_name']['value'] = $_GET['l'];
    $fields['address_1']['value'] = $_GET['a'];
    $fields['address_2']['value'] = $_GET['b'];
    // etc
    // etc

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'rt_woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields' );
```

woocommerce_admin_billing_fields() works but the shipping function does not. Any advice? I need to update the fields with $_GET variables on page load. This works perfectly for the billing fields.

Answer (score 1):

The array has `label` and `show` indexes for each item in shipping fields. There is no `value` index by default. See the `woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields` filter below.

```
self::$shipping_fields = apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields',
            array(
                'first_name' => array(
                    'label' => __( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'last_name'  => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'company'    => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Company', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'address_1'  => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Address line 1', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'address_2'  => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Address line 2', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'city'       => array(
                    'label' => __( 'City', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'postcode'   => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'country'    => array(
                    'label'   => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'show'    => false,
                    'type'    => 'select',
                    'class'   => 'js_field-country select short',
                    'options' => array( '' => __( 'Select a country / region&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) ) + WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries(),
                ),
                'state'      => array(
                    'label' => __( 'State / County', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'class' => 'js_field-state select short',
                    'show'  => false,
                ),
                'phone'      => array(
                    'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
                ),
            )
        );
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer. This code is already in the woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/meta-box-data file... I need to update the actual field values from within functions.php. I do it easily with the billing fields with the code above, but the shipping fields won't update, which is odd.